# how to open old 'tex metric font' file in ubuntu/windows?

Tags: fonts, tex-core

I've been given a ''tex metric font'' file which was apparently used, by the person who gave it to me, to make a spreadsheet on Windows in the late 80s. I know nothing about LaTeX (neither does he), can anyone help me to work out how to open this file in Ubuntu (12.04) or Windows?

Thanks,
A

Comment: oops...sorry...I mean 'tex font metrics' file...

Comment: It's a file from excel 1.0, and the more I look, the more I think only excel 1.0 can be used to open it. I don't know any other detail about the file, that's all it says in the properties...

Comment: I have access to excel 2010,2003 and '97 from work's and parents' computers, but I'll see how I go. The file seems to be from an old 80s Mac haha. Thank you!

Comment: I think the tfm file is not tex font metric file, but a file describing forms in excel

Comment: As @Guido says, this does not look like a TeX question at all, but one about another file format that just happens to have the same initials as a TeX one.